# PDO query using $_GET generating SQL syntax error

Tags: php, mysql, pdo

This code:

```
    try {
    $stmt = $conn->prepare('SELECT id, title, description, category, gallery_path FROM posts.post WHERE id = :id');
    $stmt->execute(array(':id' => $_GET['id']));
    $row = $stmt->fetch();
```

Is generating this error:

> SQLSTATE[42000]: Syntax error or access violation: 1064 You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MariaDB server version for the right syntax to use near 'FROM posts.post WHERE id = '6'' at line 1

Now, I do realize that it's trying to compare a string (the value `$_GET` returned from the url) with a integer (id), but I do not know how can I solve this.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: I think you are passing `id` as a string and not as a integer, try using `intval($_GET['id'])` (you should filter $_GET before blindly passing it to a query)

Comment: MySQL *should* interpret it correctly @Rabin

Comment: sounds like a non-existant column to me or a hidden unicode non-breaking space.

Comment: Try `$stmt->execute(array(':id' => trim($_GET['id'])));` just to make sure there are no hidden gems surrounding the value. cc/ @Fred-ii-

Comment: What is `posts.post`?

Comment: Btw; did you even connect with PDO, if at all? The question received many comments but you are not present. So, I for one have stayed here long enough, so I am no longer present in the question. You can @ someone or take it up with the answer given below, given if it is still viewable. Good luck.

Comment: @Fred-ii- It does exist, I'm quite sure.

Comment: @JayBlanchard woah, that solved it! Please put your solution as an answer so I can choose it as solution. Thank you!

Comment: @resch sure, probably because of that hidden unicode [I mentioned](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/43922370/pdo-query-using-get-generating-sql-syntax-error?noredirect=1#comment74878199_43922370), or some type of hidden code I said earlier.

Comment: Done @resch - glad to help!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Looks like you have some hidden character or BOM in your `$_GET` variable: Use [`trim()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.trim.php) to clean it up:

```
$stmt->execute(array(':id' => trim($_GET['id'])));
```

Comment: I'd call this one a team effort ;-)

Comment: Roger that @Fred-ii-!

Comment: @JayBlanchard If I were you I would credit Fred's comment in the answer. Thanks, anyway!

Comment: @resch It's all good :-) Jay came up with the `trim()` option.